# Str_Extract Issues: Missing Patterns

Tags: r, stringr

I have a list of colors I am trying to extract from the sample dataset. It seems to miss some colors and find others.

```
color_list <- c("gray", "brown", "green", "plum", "mist", "forest", "sienna", "grape", "ruby", "emerald", "copper", 
                "silver", "gold", "blue")
str_extract(df, fixed(color_list, ignore_case = TRUE))
[1] "GRAY"   NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       "silver" "GOLD"   "blue"
```

Yet the first match should be "silver".

Sample Data:

```
structure(list(df = c("Tsilver flash mirror", "E:~ ADD FLASH FRONT MI", 
"E:~", "E##T Color: G 15#3; MC", "E:~ ## PLEASE USE 8 BA", "E:~ ## blue flash ##", 
"E:~ ## Silver Mirror #", "Ssilver mirror", "E:~ ## Treatment: Fee-", 
"E:~Further Instruction", "E:~ ## FORREST GRAY Xp", "ESILVER", 
"EGOLD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"))
```

And is it also possible to do a "fuzzy" matching with Str_Extract? As there are some misspellings of colors in the data.

Comment: ```str_extract_all(df, paste(color_list,collapse = "|"))```

Comment: @M-M this code returns only (3) results back when there are at least (5) in this sample data.

Comment: That's because it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will output a dataframe with a column for the extracted. I put in the tolower() function to change the example to all lowercase. If you want "fuzzy" matching, you may want to look into regular expressions. https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html

```
 example <- structure(list(df = c("Tsilver flash mirror", "E:~ ADD FLASH FRONT MI", 
"E:~", "E##T Color: G 15#3; MC", "E:~ ## PLEASE USE 8 BA", "E:~ ## blue flash ##", 
"E:~ ## Silver Mirror #", "Ssilver mirror", "E:~ ## Treatment: Fee-", 
"E:~Further Instruction", "E:~ ## FORREST GRAY Xp", "ESILVER", 
"EGOLD")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"))

color_list <- c("gray", "brown", "green", "plum", "mist", "forest", "sienna", "grape", "ruby", "emerald", "copper", 
                "silver", "gold", "blue")

example %>% 
  mutate(extract = str_extract(tolower(df), paste(color_list, collapse = "|")))
```